# No module named instapy

Tags: python, instagram-api

```
``# Import the InstaPy module and create a new session
from instapy import instapy
session = InstaPy()

# Log in to Instagram
session.login(username="", password="")

# Follow multiple users
users_to_follow = ["joshuaa.ag", "ramc.haran7519", "mandeepsdheer", "yeshvanshka", "mariaedwardsxifnrcodja",
                   "shubhamlodhi839", "nataliefirkowska", "frasesreais98", "iran.traderir", "_niki_chaki_",
                   "laxma.n9883", "wesleysampaio2023", "neysha.cuevas.73", "efrenndiaz", "sajid__iri", "abbygibson08",
                   "syds______knee", "tu_rubia_privv3", "jxchiu_jewelry", "jarodbannister9", "blaccheaven_events",
                   "mariaeazuaje15", "mileidy.rangel", "shya.mlal8926", "al__ageed", "mahesana_ni_hasti_302",
                   "randym518", "aashumathur7", "kingsxd99", "afdrtv4", "luljace_", "pi.ntukumar1434",
                   "raquel_lysette", "brooklynng33", "saraa.hhart", "its___mary___girl", "xavie_r7603",
                   "vaibhavrao2023", "r_usl_y", "donsmith5126", "rajeev141singh", "get0ffmyblick123", "sami_p1890",
                   "buck.eyboo", "nannhe3619", "imran__bhai_99gsb", "kabaddi____lover____baihar", "ronalperez11111"]
session.follow_users(usernames=users_to_follow)

# Unfollow users who don't follow back
session.unfollow_users(amount=10, nonFollowers=True, style="FIFO")

# Send a message to users who have the word "python" in their bio
session.send_message("hello", ["python"])

# Like posts that have the tag "python"
session.like_by_tags(["python"], amount=2)

# Comment on a post from the user "python"
user_id = session.get_user_id_from_username("python")
media_id = session.get_last_user_medias(user_id)[0]
session.comment(media_id, "This is very nice")

# Get the list of followers and following for the current user
followers_list = session.get_user_followers()
following_list = session.get_user_following()
```

`

`After constructing my Instagram bot, it tells on line 2 that it will not execute since no module by the name of instapy is located in my code. I installed instapy using the command line after adding my Python file to the environment variable.``

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.
Please claim your question clear in this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can use to debug why your import is not working. Assuming you are on a unix environment. Given the lack of information, the method you use to execute your code is probably using a different python than the one you installed the package in.

1. `which python`. This will show you which python executable is being used to run your code.
2. `where python`. If by any chance you have multiple versions of python installed, this will show where they all are.
3. `echo $PATH`. This will show you your path, and therefore all of the file directories the OS looks for python executables in. This can help you debug why your python executable is wrong (if it is wrong).
4. `pip list`. This will show you all of the python packages you have installed in the python program being used in the command line.

Comment: Hello @fooiey 1. Python 3.11.2 version 2. IDLE (Python 3.11 64-bit), Python 3.11 (64-bit), Python 3.11 Manuals (64-bit), Python 3.11 Module Docs (64-bit) this all in my programs folder for python 3. instapy is showing up on pip list